# How to inject Android Context to top level functions

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have util functions as top-level functions and some of them need Context.
These functions are used in viewmodels.

Currently I have a reference for Context in custom Application class and use it from util functions, and now I want to integrate dependency injection (Hilt, but dagger 2 way should be similar)

So I guess I should create something like ApplicationContextModule and inject Context, but I'm wondering where I should inject Context.

Should I inject Context to ViewModels that use util functions? or should I inject it to top-level function directly (I'm not even sure if I can inject it to top-level function yet)?

Answer (score 0):

You should't use context in ViewModel, use Application instead:

DaggerAppComponent:

```
@Component(modules = [YourModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance app: Application): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component = DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var component: AppComponent
            private set
    }
}
```

Manitfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="project">

    <application
        android:name=".App">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

ViewModel (or any other class that u inject by hilt or dagger):

```
class YourViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val app: Application
) : ViewModel() {

   // code
   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface OkHttpClientEntryPoint {
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient
}
```

step 2

```
 val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(appContext, OkHttpClientEntryPoint::class.java).provideOkHttpClient()
```